# Comparisons of multiplier circuits

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits, circuit-design

Could someone please explain some of the advantages/disadvantages of the wallace multiplier circuit vs a shifting and adding multiplier circuit vs an shift register multiplying circuit? We went over them briefly in class but didn't get to in depth and I'm trying to sort out which is better in what situation or even overall of applicable, and why.

The wallace multiplier is pretty straight forward and simple design (to design, the physical thing seems quite tedious) but quite huge... The shifting and adding one seems better sized and quite simple but it does have an output going back in which I guess could slow things down? But then with all the things going on it the The shift register I guess seems like a nice median but not sure if I'm missing anything there.